# LINQ Query to bring back next item in sequence

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ and stuck. I have a collection of steps.  Each has a unique ID, an ID for who the individual step is assigned to, and a sequence (0-7).  I'm trying to pass in the unique ID of the step but return the ID of the person who is assigned to the next step.  My current query looks like this (I know it's wrong, just trying to illustrate:

```
var nextApproverId = _context.ApprovalSteps
     .Where(p => p.Header.Active == true &&
     p.Sequence == (p.Sequence== (step.sequence + 1))
     .Select(p => p.AssignedApproverId);
```

The steps look like this

```
Id      AssignedApproverId      Sequence
123           100                  0
438           101                  1
```

So I'm trying to pass in Id 123 with the intention of returning Id 438.

Comment: Could you put some sample data and the result that you want

Comment: What is `step.stepID` ?? I would make two queries: one to get the step by Id, another to get the next step, I suspect it should be faster than trying to make one single query with joins.

Comment: Kindly clarify what `step.stepID.sequence` refers to as asked by Alisson

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var currentId = 123;
var nextApproverId = _context.ApprovalSteps.Single(s => s.sequence == _context.ApprovalSteps.Single(p => p.id == currentId).sequence + 1).Id;
//Returns 438 in your example
```

Create 2 querys:

One to get the current sequence:

```
var currentSequence = _context.ApprovalSteps.Single(p => p.id == currentId).sequence;
```

The other to use the currentSequence to get the next step:

```
var nextStep = context.ApprovalSteps.Single(s => s.sequence == _currentSequence + 1);
```

nextStep.Id gets you the ID of that step.

Merged:

```
 var nextApproverId = _context.ApprovalSteps.Single(s => s.sequence == _context.ApprovalSteps.Single(p => p.id == currentId).sequence + 1).Id;
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should consider moving `_context.ApprovalSteps.Single(p => p.id == currentId).sequence` outisde of the outer `Single` - otherwise it will be being evaluated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem lies here:

```
 p.Sequence == (p.Sequence== (step.sequence + 1))
```

This part should be

```
 var nextApproverId = _context.ApprovalSteps
     .Where(p => p.Header.Active == true &&
     p.Sequence == (step.sequence + 1))
     .Select(p => p.AssignedApproverId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible answer, see output [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aKO4vy)

```
steps.Select(x =>steps.IndexOf(tags.Where(ele => ele.m_id == id).FirstOrDefault()) + 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

> I created a sample with my own class structure as described by OP a person class with unique ID.
>   To solve this OP needs to find the Index of current Id `in My case Index of 3 is 1` then iterate over the list and see if current object index is 1 less then the one provided by user here `In my case the index of output which is "2" is 2 so 2-1 == index of the Id provided as argument by OP`

```
class person
{
  public string m_name;
  public int m_id;
  public person(string name,int id)
  {
     m_name = name;
     m_id = id;
  }
}
```

// Main class

```
List<person> steps= new List<person>();
steps.Add(new person("sample",1));
steps.Add(new person("sample1",3));
steps.Add(new person("sample2",2));

int id = 3;
int sample = steps.Where(x => steps.IndexOf(x) - 1 == (steps.IndexOf(steps.Where(ele => ele.m_id == id).FirstOrDefault()))).Select(x => x.m_id).FirstOrDefault();

int sample2 =  steps.Select(x =>steps.IndexOf(steps.Where(ele => ele.m_id == id).FirstOrDefault()) + 1).FirstOrDefault();

// output is 2
```

Comment: How is this gonna help the TS? Please give some information about how you thought this out.